# Connect to MYSQL with VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connection

I am trying to connect to a MYSQL database using VB.NET to handle some simple tasks at a page level. Usually the connections are made to a MYSQL database. I have downloaded a MYSQL-CONNECTOR 6.0.7. How do I reference or add this to my web project so that I can create the connection and use the provided methods?

In the unzipped package I download I do not see any dll files so not sure what to do with this ATM, I am used to seeing a bin folder which contains this. Maybe I have a bad download any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you downloaded the ZIP archive, then generally this is the source code distribution. You need to open MySQLClient.sln in Visual Studio and build the MySql.Data project to produce MySql.Data.dll in the bin folder.

Comment: Is there any reason why a dll wouldn't be included just our of curiosity?

Comment: They include the dll in the Windows Installer package, but not the source. The source is provided so you can compile a specific build of the dll to meet your needs. For example the project is .NET 4 CLR by default, but I need 3.5 so having them provide the dll in the source would have done me no good. I guess they could have provided the dll in different forms, but that's what they have the installer for :P

Answer (score 0):

the last version is 6.4.3 download from http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ , add reference for the unzip folder and us it as sqlClient it has the same class only have to append My to the class name

Comment: I have the same problem here. You must reference an assembly not a folder, where do you find this in the unzipped folder?